# How to do backup in C# application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, backup, restore

I will try to do a backup database from C# application. I found more tutorials how do that. In the new project copy some solution and run. All the time I got one connection error like:

> "backup failed for server ".

In this line:

> source.SqlBackup(server);

Do you know how I resolve this? I think that problem concerns connection to server (it's broken?).

Below you can see a Backup method:

```
public static void BackupDatabase(string backUpFile)
{
    ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@".\SQLEXPRESS");
    Server server = new Server(con);
    Backup source = new Backup();
    source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    source.Database = "DB";
    BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
    source.Devices.Add(destination);
    source.SqlBackup(server);
    con.Disconnect();
    MessageBox.Show("Kopia wykonana!");
}
```

Comment: What is value of `backUpFile`? Have your sql server service account permission to write to that location?

Comment: You should put a try/catch around that, and display the value of `ex.ToString()`

Comment: In the backuFile I enter the path to backup eg. BackupDatabase(@"C:\backup\backup.bak");
Any permission? I don't know I'm connecting to SQL Server use Windows Authentication.

Comment: Please look into your inner exceptions and give us some more details from that. We may be able to help you faster.

Comment: If you are developing this app locally can you try to add "Everyone" user which has "Full Control" for "C:\backup\" folder ? Also, if I remember correctly, when a backup process fails it logs error into SQL Server logs, do you see anything helpful there ?

Comment: I got this:

2013-03-01 16:42:44.45 spid54      
Error: 18204, Severity: 16, State: 1.

2013-03-01 16:42:44.45 spid54      BackupDiskFile::CreateMedia: Backup device 'C:\sql backups\blah.bak' failed to create. Operating system error 3(System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki.).

Comment: Added full control for PC Users to the backup folder on C:\ drive helped! But just I have one question: how I can modify above C# code that program should be yourself create backup folder on C:\ and do a copy database? Currently I did it.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things for you to try.

1. Make sure your database name is correct

   source.Database = "DB"; // Check the database name is actually 'DB'.
2. I had some issues in the past using `ServerConnection` with a connection string, even though the syntax allows you to do so. What i did was to create an `SqlConnection` from the connection string and then give that to `ServerConnection`.

   ```
   string connectionString = "Your connection string goes here";

   SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

   ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);
   ```
3. I would also try initializing the backup object.

   ```
   source.Initialize = true;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Added full control for PC Users to the backup folder on C:\ drive helped! Thanks all for help! But just I have one question: how I can modify above C# code that program should be yourself create backup folder on C:\ and do a copy database? Currently I must do it manually.